# Why executable files (mode x flagged) under a folder cannot run?

Tags: shell, file-permissions

I thought that a script file under my /data folder cannot be executed is because it is not set 'x' permission , but after chmod +x, it still cannot run, even my handmade simple test script cannot if I put it under the /data folder. What else to check?
Complains permission denied.

```
build$ lsattr /data
-------------e-- /data/plug
-------------e-- /data/lost+found
-------------e-- /data/qt-6.6.0-base

build$ lsattr -d /data
-------------e-- /data

build$ ls -ld /data
drwxr-xr-x 6 gw root 4096 Oct 30 14:14 /data

build$ ls -l /data/script
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gw gw 22 Oct 30 14:14 /data/script

$ sh /data/script
aaa
$ /data/script
bash: /data/script: Permission denied
$ cat /data/script
#!/bin/sh

echo 'aaa'
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr 19  2020 /bin/sh -> dash
```

The disk is        description: ATA Disk, product: ST1000DM010-2EP1, vendor: Seagate, physical id: 0.0.0, bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0

Comment: Edit the question and add the output of `ls -ld /data` and `ls -l /data/script` so that the actual permissions and ownership can be seen and not just the extended attributes.

Comment: How exactly you are trying to execute it (e.g. describe precisely your actions)? Does it run with explicit shell, e.g. `bash /data/script`? Does it contain a correct sha-bang, `#!/bin/bash` or something like that? What is the containing file system and its mount options? // Do you really have a file `/data/script`? I am asking because this is not a [FHS-approved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) location, and no sane people in a business environment call script files just `script`. What is the **real full name** (e.g. with path) of the file containing the script?

Comment: What does `mount | grep /data` say?

Comment: Thanks @Ginnungagap `/dev/sdb1 on /data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,data=ordered,user)`, btw. fstab says: `UUID=1b05a724-69cc-4e5a-98cf-81c16e6e1996 /data           ext4    rw,user,x-gvfs-show,nosuid,nofail 0       2
` how to change the `noexec` thing?

Comment: [Edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1146829/edit) your question and put it there. Well, `noexec` is likely set in the `/etc/fstab`. Better don't put scripts there, or call with explicit shell; the `noexec` is a security thing which is likely put there for a reason.

Comment: Yeah, but fstab didn't say 'noexec' so why it got mouted as noexec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [`man mount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount):

> **user**
>
> Allow an ordinary user to mount the filesystem. The name of the mounting user is written to mtab so that he can unmount the filesystem again. **This option implies the options *noexec*, *nosuid*, and *nodev*** (unless overridden by subsequent options, as in the option line user,exec,dev,suid).

highlight by me.